# Debounce Email Validation with Elementor Pro

Tags: elementor, email-verification, debouncing

I am having issues getting the Debounce API to work with Elementor Forms to verify the email addresses that users enter on my website. Has anyone successfully integrated the Debounce API with their Elementor Site via Wordpress?

I've already added required code to the server backend and also css code to the input of the form, but no luck with connecting to the Debounce service.

Cheers